Density theorem for $2$-categories
Let $C$ be a category and $F: C^{op} \to \operatorname{Set}$ a presheaf on $C$. The density theorem states that $F$ is the colimit of representable presheaves.
I would like to know if there is an analogue of this in the following $2$-category theoretical setting. Let $\operatorname{Cat}$ be the strict $2$-category of $1$-categories and left $\mathcal C$ be a $1$-category considered as a strict $2$-category. Let $\mathcal F: \mathcal C^{op} \to \operatorname{Cat}$ be a pseudofunctor, i.e. a mapping that respects composition up to a natural equivalence: $\alpha_{f,g}: \mathcal F(fg) \implies \mathcal F(f)\circ \mathcal F(g)$.
Can we say that $\mathcal F$ is the (pseudo-)colimit of representable $2$-presheaves? What if we require $\mathcal F$ to be a strict functor?
An issue might be that any canonical choice of representable pseudo-functor on $\mathcal C$ will actually be a strict functor.
There is an $(\infty, 1)$-category version of the density theorem but I don't know how it specialises to this setting.

Have you looked at the literature on the topic? For example at https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055 ?
